# Concat static URL string with dynamic xslt folder name umbraco

Tags: xslt, transform, umbraco

I'm trying to add a string in front of the src of the image html below so that the image tag looks like this...

```
<img width="630" height="540" src="http://www.adifferentserver.com/media/6533/animage.jpg">
```

Currently the xslt outputs this

```
<img width="630" height="540" src="/media/6533/animage.jpg">
```

The following xslt produces the html below..

```
<ul class="overview">
  <xsl:for-each select="$mediaItems/Image">
    <xsl:variable name="picFile" select="umbracoFile"/>

    <li>
        <img>
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="./umbracoFile"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img width="630" height="540" src="/media/6533/animage.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the xpath function '**concat**' :

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('http://www.adifferentserver.com',./umbracoFile)"/>
```